# How can I find out a servlet's URL?

Tags: java, servlets

Let's say I have this in my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>MainServ</display-name>
    <servlet-name>MainServ</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>MainServ</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MainServ</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MainServ</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Imagine I'm in that servlet's `doGet` method. Is there anyway of getting at the `/MainServ` value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Via [`HttpServletRequest.getServletPath`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath()); from the Javadoc:

> This path starts with a "/" character and includes either the servlet name or a path to the servlet, but does not include any extra path information or a query string.

E.g.:

```
String path = req.getServletPath();
```

...if you've called the first argument to `doGet` `req`.